# SSMS 2008 R2 Intermittantly Hangs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm using SSMS 2008 R2 on a server with the database located on it as well, so everything is local.  While I am using it it will intermittently hang (hour glass, not responding in header when click on window) and then after 30 seconds or so come back as if nothing was wrong and continue on.  I tried turning off the intellisense and no luck.  CPU is idle, which was the first thing I started to look at.  When it hangs, the rest of the desktop is completely responsive.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be a query that it's internally running taking a really long time or being blocked? You could check what's going on in the database when it's stuck.

Comment: I can be sitting not touching the keyboard and it will hang.  Then come back between 15 and 60 seconds later.  I think it is something internal that is waiting for.  I will try running a second instance when it hangs and see if I can catch it.

Comment: Do you have nested TRY / CATCH groups in your script? I get this problem when I use these, even when the script runs correctly editing it can be a real nightmare.